# Delete the row based on order column using perl

Tags: perl

I have a table separated by ',' I want to order and test if the value from num+1 exists in num column, or the value from num+2 exists in num, or the value from num+3 field exists in num, or the value from num+4 field exists in num for each row then delete the row if true.

my script is:

```
#!"C:\perl\bin\perl.exe"

use strict;
use warnings;

my $file_name = shift @ARGV;

die "Usage ./$1 <file_to_be_processed> > <output_file>" unless defined $file_name;

my $dic; # This is going to hold all values to be excluded.

open IN, "<", $file_name or die "Could not open $file_name $!\n";

while(<IN>) {
        chomp;
        @_ = split /,/;
        shift @_;
        map{$dic->{$_}++} @_;
}

close IN;

open IN, "<", $file_name or die "Could not open $file_name $!\n";

while(<IN>) {
        chomp;
        @_ = split /,/;
        print $_."\n" unless defined $dic->{$_[0]};
}

close IN;
```

there is my table:

```
num,num+1,num+2,num+3,num+4
1014,1015,1016,1017,1018
1015,1016,1017,1018,1019
1019,1020,1021,1022,1023
1025,1026,1027,1028,1029
1030,1031,1032,1033,1034
```

there is expected result:

```
num,num+1,num+2,num+3,num+4
1014,1015,1016,1017,1018
1019,1020,1021,1022,1023
1025,1026,1027,1028,1029
1030,1031,1032,1033,1034
```

My script works but excludes num 1019 from result, there is output of actual script:

```
num,num+1,num+2,num+3,num+4
1014,1015,1016,1017,1018
1025,1026,1027,1028,1029
1030,1031,1032,1033,1034
```

Comment: You should ***never*** use the built-in variable `@_` except for its proper purpose, which is to receive that parameters passed to a subroutine, or possibly to modify them if the are outward parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to dynamically change your hash when you skip a line:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %dic;
my $pos = tell DATA; # Remember where the data start.

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @ar = split /,/;
    # Fix SO syntax highlighting error: /
    shift @ar;
    $dic{$_}++ for @ar;
}

seek DATA, $pos, 0; # Back to the data start.

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @ar = split /,/;
    if ($dic{ $ar[0] }) {
        delete $dic{ $_ } for @ar[1 .. $#ar]; # <-- this was missing!
    } else {
        print "$_\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
1014,1015,1016,1017,1018
1015,1016,1017,1018,1019
1019,1020,1021,1022,1023
1025,1026,1027,1028,1029
1030,1031,1032,1033,1034
```

Comment: Please how can i sort the first column befor test?

Comment: @ImiiIik: Are you on linux? `sort -nt, -k1,1` might be enough.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a misuse of `map` to me - if you're not using the result of `map` then you should probably be using a `for` loop instead.

But that aside - what you're doing here is creating a list of every symbol in column 1,2,3,4 and excluding a line if it exists?

Because your sample data includes 1019 on the previous line, that's why it's being excluded.

Your `$dic` looks like:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '1016' => 2,
          '1021' => 1,
          '1022' => 1,
          '1028' => 1,
          '1034' => 1,
          'num+3' => 1,
          '1017' => 2,
          'num+1' => 1,
          '1015' => 1,
          '1020' => 1,
          'num+2' => 1,
          '1023' => 1,
          '1026' => 1,
          '1019' => 1,
          '1031' => 1,
          '1027' => 1,
          '1032' => 1,
          '1033' => 1,
          '1018' => 2,
          '1029' => 1,
          'num+4' => 1
        };
```

As 1019 is in it, the 1019 line gets skipped.

Also:

- `Data::Dumper` is useful for seeing what's in a data structure.
- don't use `map` like that. Use a  `for` loop.

Something like:

```
while(<IN>) {
    chomp;
    $dic->{$_}++ for split /,/;
}
```

- don't use `@_` like that - it's a special variable, with a specific meaning. Call it something else.
- current good practice is to use a lexical filehandle with `open`. e.g. `open ( my $in, '<', $filename ) or die $!;` because of keeping the scope down.
- if you just want to check the first column, you can assign like this: `my ( $col, @rest ) = split /,/;` and just test `$col`. Or you can skip the `chomp` entirely and just do:

  ```
  print unless defined $dic->{(split /,/)[0]};
  ```

Answer (score 1):

1019 is being skipped because even though the 1015 row will be skipped in the second loop, the 1019 key was already defined for `$dic` in your first loop.

```
map{$dic->{$_}++} @_;
```

On the second iteration of the first loop (the 1015 row), that line is setting keys 1016, 1017, 1018, and 1019 (to 1). Then in your second loop:

```
print $_."\n" unless defined $dic->{$_[0]};
```

your `unless` skips 1015, but doesn't do anything to remove the keys that the 1015 row defined with it, so it continues to remove the 1019 row.

Comment: All that you say is true, but your solution isn't a ***solution***!

Comment: Correct, it's an answer.

Comment: You've explained why the OP has the observed behaviour, but have done nothing to help him to resolve it

Comment: Still correct, I'm not refuting you. Rather, I am under the impression that offering an explanatory answer that will lead the OP to correcting their own problem is not only sufficient but desirable. Link me to where on SO it says answers must necessarily be spelled out solutions and I will concede your point, and modify my approach in the future. edit: i.e., clearly pointing out the problem is in fact doing something to help them resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly then this is all you need

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %seen;

while ( <DATA> ) {
    chomp;
    my @fields = split /,/;
    if ( not $seen{ shift @fields } ) {
        $seen{$_} = 1 for @fields;
        print "$_\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
1014,1015,1016,1017,1018
1015,1016,1017,1018,1019
1019,1020,1021,1022,1023
1025,1026,1027,1028,1029
1030,1031,1032,1033,1034
```

### output

```
1014,1015,1016,1017,1018
1019,1020,1021,1022,1023
1025,1026,1027,1028,1029
1030,1031,1032,1033,1034
```

Comment: You have provided the OP with working code, but have done nothing to help them understand what was wrong with theirs or why yours works vOv

Comment: @swornabsent: Yes, I'm less than happy with this myself. But I don't enjoy combat in the comments so I will leave you to imagine my rejoinders yourself